# Explain why $(f \cdot g)(x)=0$ then $f(x)=0$ or $g(x)=0$ is the wrong answer

Tags: functions

We have a test with Right/Wrong answers. A question from the test says:

For functions $f$ and $g$ which both have $x \in \mathbb R$, we have a function $(f \cdot g)(x)=0$, then it is true that either $f(x)=0$ or $g(x)=0$?

The answer to the test is that the above statement is wrong but why is that wrong? I can't explain it. Please, explain.

Comment: The question is worded poorly. For fixed $x$, the statement is true.

Comment: What does (for example) $Df=R$ mean to you?

Comment: It means that x∈R for both f(x) and g(x)

Comment: @Skoutas: I’ve added a bit to my answer in an attempt to address the comment in your attempted edit; see if it helps. (But please don’t try to edit the answer; if you have a question, ask it in the comments.)

Comment: Does $\circ$ denote function composition or point-wise multiplication?

Comment: @AndresMejia - I think your edit just totally changed the meaning of the question, and invalidated all of the prior answers.

Comment: @mbeckish my apologies, I just saw that it was unformatted, so that was hasty.

Answer (score 5):

Suppose that

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
0,\text{if }x\text{ is rational}\\
1,\text{if }x\text{ is irrational}
\end{cases}$$

and

$$g(x)=\begin{cases}
0,\text{if }x\text{ is irrational}\\
1,\text{if }x\text{ is rational}\;.
\end{cases}$$

Neither function is constantly $0$, but $(fg)(x)=0\cdot1=0$ for each $x\in\Bbb R$.

**Added:** Every real number is either rational or irrational. If $x$ is rational, then $f(x)=0$, so $(fg)(x)=f(x)\cdot g(x)=0\cdot1=0$. If, on the other hand, $x$ is irrational, then $g(x)=0$, so $(fg)(x)=f(x)\cdot g(x)=1\cdot 0=0$. In every case $(fg)(x)=0$, yet neither $f$ nor $g$ is the constant $0$ function.

Comment: You labeled wrongly your functions.

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD: Copy/paste error; thanks!

Comment: Note that this depends on interpretation. We can interpret this as either saying 

$[\forall x \in \mathbb{R} \ f(x) = 0] \ \lor [\forall x \in \mathbb{R} \ g(x) = 0]$ or $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}[f(x) = 0 \lor g(x) = 0]$. You are presuming the former one, whereas the statement is true if we assume the latter one.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122: There would be very little doubt as to the correct interpretation even if we didn’t know the answer, and in this case the known answer makes it very clear what interpretation is intended.

Answer (score 4):

Define 
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
0,\text{if }x=0\\
1,\text{if }x>0
\end{cases}$$

$$g(x)=\begin{cases}
1,\text{if }x=0\\
0,\text{if }x>0
\end{cases}$$

$(fg)(x)=0$ for all $x \in [0, \infty)$, but neither is the zero function.

Answer (score 0):

With simple functions:
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}0&\text{if } x<0,\\x&\text{if } x\ge 0\end{cases}\qquad g(x)=\begin{cases}x&\text{if } x<0,\\0&\text{if } x0\ge 0\end{cases}.$$

Intuitively, $f(x)g(x)=0$ means that at each $x$, one of $f,g$ takes the value $0$. But should it be always the same function?